# randomly select n lines from a file with possible repetition

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I Have a text file with more than 1 million lines. The individual lines are not very big (about 200-270 characters each).

I am trying to randomly pick 60% of the number of lines in input, where each line can be repeated in the output. In the above example, my output would have 600,000 lines, but only 500,000 lines out of them might be unique. I also need the lines which were not picked at all, in a different output file. Any individual line should not appear in both the output files.

Each line in a input file has a record like below.

- Record1
- Record2
- Record3
- Record4
- Record5
- Record6
- Record7

If I am trying to pick 5 random lines in a file output1.txt, where each line can be repeated. Lets say following were the lines picked and are in output1.txt

- Record3
- Record5
- Record2
- Record2
- Record5

The remaining records should go to output2.txt.

- Record1
- Record4
- Record6
- Record7

The order of the records does not matter.

I think I can write code to do this using Java, but I was wondering I can do it quickly using some command or scripting. I tried using 'shuf' to pick the lines, but how can I then make sure that the lines which have been picked, don't appear in the second output I am trying to get.

I am working on a Linux machine. Any suggestions or comments are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - What have you tried? This isn't a place to get code written for you.

Comment: Sounds to me like the first part's pretty easy (a few simple lines of php or whatever) but the second part, i.e., outputting separately the ones that weren't in the first part, makes it harder...

Comment: I am sorry if It sounds like I am looking for someone to tell me the code. What I am looking for is any ideas or commands which already do what i need. BY the way i already wrote in the question what i tried.

Comment: @Ben: exactly where i am stuck. I can get the output for 1st part by simply using 'shuf' command.

Comment: You must clarify and be very explicit. Exactly what should each of these two files have? If I interpret you correctly... the mathematical jargon you are looking for is as follows: You have a set of 1 million elements and you wish to pick sample elements "without replacement". Additionally, you want this to partition your set into two sets: the picked and unpicked elements. Indeed, if you are representing the set as an array, you can shuffle the array and split it in two: let the first 60% of elements be chosen, and let the remaining 40% of the elements by unchosen. What is the problem?

Comment: For example, supposing your set was `population = set(range(10**6))`, you could just do `x = list(population)` `random.shuffle(x)` `return x[:int(0.6 * 10**6)], x[:int(0.6 * 10**6):]`. Where does "... out of them might be unique" come in? You also mention Java when your question is tagged as Python and Perl.

Comment: @ninjagecko: your ideas won't work as the initial pick is *with replacement* (the OP says `each line can be repeated in the output`) but a list of all the *unpicked* lines is also required.

Comment: @stackoverflow: I wrote in the original question that I need 2 files in my output. Also I wrote that i tried using 'shuf'. Please read the 2nd last paragraph. But, I got the impression that either I was not clear enough in my question, or people were not able to understand my question, So I edited it by just including the example. The only edit i made was including the example.

Comment: rather than worry about the text and lines, use the ${RANDOM} var to write 600,000 numbers to a file, the select from the real file based on #s in the select. Write anything else into the not-in-list-file. Good luck.

Comment: How did you get 500,000? Do you specifically want 5/6 of the lines output to be unique?

Comment: @ikegami: Just an example, "only 500,000 lines out of them might be unique".

Comment: @shellter: This kind of works. Thanks.

Comment: @Nishant Nagwani, ok, deleted my existing answer and added one that follows this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This randomly picks one line of the N lines of the file until N/6 lines are picked. The rate of duplicates is not controlled.

To save memory, we'll keep the file position of the lines in memory instead of the lines themselves. [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile) does that for us.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File  qw( );

my ($input_qfn, $picked_qfn, $unpicked_qfn) = @ARGV;

tie(my @lines, 'Tie::File', $input_qfn, autochomp => 0)
   or die;

my $num_lines = @lines;
my @unpicked_indexes = 0..$num_lines-1;
my @picked_indexes;
for (1..$num_lines*.6) {
   my $rnd_idx = int(rand($num_lines));
   $unpicked_indexes[$rnd_idx] = undef;
   push @picked_indexes, $rnd_idx;
}

open(my $picked_fh, '>', $picked_qfn)
   or die $!;
print($picked_fh $lines[$_]) for @picked_indexes;

open(my $unpicked_fh, '>', $unpicked_qfn)
   or die $!;
print($unpicked_fh $lines[$_]) for grep defined, @unpicked_indexes;
```

Comment: Added the missing bits to make this a runnable script.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Perl solution.

I seem to be writing this a lot recently, but indexing a very large text file is the best way to get random access to it without reading the entire file into memory.

This program uses the [`tell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html) operator to establish the offset of the current record within the source file, the [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) operator to return to a specific record, and [`vec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html) to keep track of which records have been selected.

Note that the `do { ... } while EXPR` form executes the do-block before first checking the condition, and has been chosen specifically for this purpose.

The program expects the file to be scanned for data to be specified on the command line. The output files are `selected.txt` for the 60% selected and `unselected.txt` for the remainder.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = shift or die "No input file specified";

open my $infh, '<', $file or die qq(Unable to open "$file" for input: $!);
my @index;
do { push @index, tell $infh } while <$infh>;

my $used = "\0" x (@index / 8 + 1);

my $outfh;

open $outfh, '>', 'selected.txt' or die $!;
my $n = 0;
while ($n++ / @index < 0.6) {
  my $rec = int rand scalar @index;
  seek $infh, $index[$rec], 0;
  print $outfh scalar <$infh>;
  vec($used, $rec, 1) = 1;
}

open $outfh, '>', 'unselected.txt' or die $!;
for my $rec (0 .. $#index) {
  next if vec($used, $rec, 1);
  seek $infh, $index[$rec], 0;
  print $outfh scalar <$infh>;
}
```

---

**Edit**

I hesitate to use a module to replace so little code, but here is a version using [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) as *ikegami* recommends in case anyone prefers this approach.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my $file = shift or die "No input file specified";

tie my @index, 'Tie::File', $file, mode => O_RDONLY
    or die qq(Unable to open "$file" for input: $!);

my $outfh;
my @used;

open $outfh, '>', 'selected.txt' or die $!;
my $n = 0;
while ($n++ / @index < 0.6) {
  my $rec = int rand scalar @index;
  print $outfh $index[$rec], "\n";
  $used[$rec]++;
}

open $outfh, '>', 'unselected.txt' or die $!;
for my $rec (0 .. $#index) {
  print $outfh $index[$rec], "\n" unless $used[$rec];
}
```

Comment: For furture reference, you might want to check Tie::File. I used it in my previously posted solution because it does all the tell and seek for you. vec() is a nice touch, but that kind of memory savings are probably not required.

Answer (score 0):

Example ~ 10% in STDOUT twice, another 50% in STDOUT once, rest 40% in STDERR

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand()} !/^$/ { r = rand(); if (r <= .60) print $0; if (r <= 0.10) print $0; if (r > .60) print $0 > "/dev/stderr"; }'
```

Note: Redirect STDOUT to one file `> file1` and STDERR to other file `2> file2` ...

Comment: I am very grateful to your for your help. But,The question clearly mentioned "I also need the lines which were not picked at all, in a different output file. Any individual line should not appear in both the output files." The only change I did was included the example. Please Read comments on the question. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it doesn't cover the repetition case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `bash script` using this code:

**without repetition of lines in the output:**

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=$(wc -l inputfile.txt | awk '{print $1}')

echo $lines

# computation of percentage of random lines we
# want to pick e.g. 60%
let percentage=$((lines*60/100))

echo $percentage

# pick the random lines
random_lines=$(sort -R inputfile.txt | head -n $percentage)

# show the random lines
echo $random_lines
```

**with repetition of lines in the output:**

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=$(wc -l inputfile.txt | awk '{print $1}')

echo $lines

# computation of percentage of random lines we
# want to pick e.g. 60%
let percentage=$((lines*60/100))

echo $percentage

# pick the random lines
for ((i=1; i<$percentage; i++))
do
  echo $(sort -R inputfile.txt | head -n 1)
done
```

Comment: Again, this doesn't allow for the requirement that `each line can be repeated in the output`.

Comment: @Thanasis Petsas: Thanks. But is sorting the entire file again and again a good idea, since the input file is as big as 1 million records.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical jargon you are looking for is as follows: You have a set of 1 million elements and you wish to pick sample elements "with replacement"; furthermore you wish to know the elements which were not picked.

```
universe = range(10**6)  # or whatever your elements are
numElementsToChoose = int(0.6*len(universe))

chosen = [random.choice(universe) for _ in range(numElementsToChoose)]
unchosen = set(universe) - set(chosen)
```

Demo:

```
>>> len(chosen), len(unchosen)
(600000, 548815)
```

(This code is inelegant because `universe` should be a set, but python doesn't natively support picking a random element from a set, only a sequence... ugh.)

Comment: I assume by set you mean a set data structure. A set data structure cannot have repeated records. Moreover, The summation of choosen and remaining can be more than the original number of lines (1000000), since records can be repeated in choosen.

Comment: @NishantNagwani: oops, thanks, edited. One also use `collections.Counter`, but if one is content storing `chosen` as a list, this works too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `shuf`, you probably have `comm`, which has the -3 option to compare two sorted files and output the lines found in only one file.